# using the same dynamical form on one page

Tags: django, forms

I know this has been asked a lot and I looked up a lot of stuff but couldn't an answer.

I have a dynamically created form where one owner can have many cars, so I'm wondering if I can create multiple car forms on my page.

```
   class CarForm (forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(CarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['owner']=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}),label='', required=False)
            self.fields['car']=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}),label='', required=False)
```

I tried with prefix but doesn't work.

```
self.fields['owner']=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}),label='', required=False, prefix='mother')
```

anyone an idea or am I on the complete wrong path here.

Comment: Have you considered using a formset? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I did, but I was hoping for an easier way since I didn't understand it

Comment: You can certainly pass multiple form instances to a view, which I've had to do on occasion when dealing with multiple dynamic forms for different model types, but Formsets are specifically designed to handle multiple instances of forms for the same type.

Comment: Are you sure formsets is correct here? Because I only want to add one of the fields not both.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. Each form, not field, will its own prefix, if you're using multiple forms of the same type. Formsets are used to create/edit multiple instances of a model at the same time. it sounds like you have one form, but with different field requirements per instance?